# Como fazer rotina de download?

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Boa tarde prezados !

Estou iniciando na programação no javascript!

comecei com algo simples !!

Uma rotina de download de arquivos , onde a ideia é, através de escolha do arquivo se faça o download , após a checagem se o arquivo existe ou não , com mensagem !

Meu código ficou bizarro eu sei !! mas está ae para quem quizer me ajudar !!

```
<html>
  
<section id="conteudo">
       <select id="opcao">  
        <option>Selecione</option> <tr>
    <option value="209901">JAN/2099</option>
    <option value="202002">FEV/2020</option>
    <option value="202003">MAR/2020</option>
    <option value="202004">ABR/2020</option>
    <option value="202005">MAI/2020</option>
    <option value="202006">JUN/2020</option>
    <option value="202007">JUL/2020</option>
    <option value="202008">AGO/2020</option>
    <option value="202009">SET/2020</option>
    <option value="202010">OUT/2020</option>
    <option value="202011">NOV/2020</option>
    <option value="202012">DEZ/2020</option>
    
    </select>


<button onclick="clickyClick()">Baixar Indice</button> <tbr>



   
<script type='text/javascript'>

        function clickyClick() {
          url = 'http://www.quarta.com.br/downloads/gfip/'+"TF" + document.getElementById("opcao").value+".zip"
         <script url='http://www.quarta.com.br/downloads/gfip/'+"TF" + document.getElementById("opcao").value+".zip" onerror="alert('Indice não disponilizado');" onload="window.open(url, '_blank');" type="text/javascript" ></script>
       
   

</script>
    
  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi o que você quer fazer, mas vamos lá.

Uma coisa que você pode fazer, é pegar essa url, e colocar ela dentro do href de um HyperLink, junto do atributo de download.

```
<a href="http:UrlLinkblablabla" download style="display: none"></a>
```

Ai basta você usar da lógica pra fazer o que você quiser com isso. Imagino que você queira que baixe o arquivo assim que você clicar no botão. Então dentro da sua função "clickyClick", você pode passar a URL pra dentro do href do HyperLink através de um pouco de JavaScript, e então dar um trigger click (também através de JavaScript) no HyperLink